# Problem with caption and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, captions

When I compile the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

I get a 'Package caption Warning'. The final output looks fine, I'm just curious what this warning means and how to get rid of it.

@Martin: \listfiles gave me this

```
*File List*
book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
caption.sty    2009/10/09 v3.1k Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2009/10/09 v3.1k caption3 kernel (AR)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
hyperref.sty    2010/04/17 v6.80x Hypertext links for LaTeX
ltxcmds.sty    2010/04/16 v1.6 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2010/01/28 v1.3 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Provides hex, PDF name and string conversions 
                   (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2010/04/01 v0.9 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
ifpdf.sty    2010/01/28 v2.1 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
hycolor.sty    2009/12/12 v1.6 Color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2009/12/12 xcolor patch
letltxmacro.sty    2008/06/24 v1.3 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
pd1enc.def    2010/04/17 v6.80x Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
kvoptions.sty    2010/02/22 v3.7 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2010/03/25 v1.12 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hpdftex.def    2010/04/17 v6.80x Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2010/03/24 v1.5 Hooks at very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2010/03/16 v1.6 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2009/12/18 v1.1 Provides unlimited unique counter (HO)
nameref.sty    2010/04/17 v2.39 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2009/12/18 v1.3 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Maybe the problem is caused by the 6.80x version of hyperref?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted Axel Sommerfeldt, author of caption about this incompatibility introduced with hyperref v6.79l last year. Axel fixed it by releasing caption version 3.1l in January.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have an old version of caption or hyperref? I don't get any warnings when compiling your example. Try adding \listfiles and compare with the File list from a run on my system.

As a side note; you don't need to specify the pdftex driver for hyperref if you are using pdftex in pdf-mode.

```
 *File List*
book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 caption.sty    2009/10/09 v3.1k Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2009/10/09 v3.1k caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
hyperref.sty    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hypertext links for LaTeX
   ifpdf.sty    2009/04/10 v2.0 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2008/11/04 v1.4 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
 hycolor.sty    2009/10/02 v1.5 Code for color options of hyperref/bookmark (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2009/10/02 xcolor patch
  pd1enc.def    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2007/12/12 v1.2 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2007/09/09 v1.2 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
kvoptions.sty    2009/08/13 v3.4 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2009/07/30 v1.5 Key value parser with default handler support (HO)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2007/09/28 v1.0 Data type bit set (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable integer calculations (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2007/11/11 v1.1 Expandable big integer calculations (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2009/09/23 v0.6 LuaTeX support for pdfTeX utility functions (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2009/04/17 v1.2 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2009/08/05 v1.0 Some LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2008/07/31 v1.9 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2009/10/09 v6.79a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
 nameref.sty    2007/05/29 v2.31 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2008/08/11 v3.1 Data extraction from references (HO)
compendium.out
compendium.out
 ***********
```